# Rename [gas] to [gnu-assembler]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

We currently use [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) for questions about the GNU assembler. However, Google Apps Script is also commonly abbreviated as "gas", so questions about it are often mistagged, even though [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) already exists (and in fact, a lot of times, the asker applies both tags). Here's a small sampling of some recently mistagged questions:

- [Can somebody help out what is the issue with the following GAS code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61852587/7509065)
- [Publishing a message to a telegram Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61797037/7509065)
- [How to render multiple html lists with AppScrip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61668321/7509065)
- [Insert list item into a specific Table of google doc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61499242/7509065)
- [How can I add a QR Code Scanner on Google app script (web app)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61242271/7509065)
- [Process binary data retrieved with UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61234008/7509065)
- [Google forms. Send email based on answer. Error on namedValues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61098763/7509065)
- [Extract Hyperlinks Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60935636/7509065)

I think we should rename [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler) to make the tag's actual purpose more clear, and hopefully put a stop to this mistagging.

Comment: One problem I see with a rename is that some/many of the users that already expect to use "gas" would not be able to locate the renamed tag. It would only take one person adding "gas" to a new question to recreate the tag.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm But isn't that an argument to keep every ambiguous tag? And even so, at least there's a minimal rep requirement to create a new tag.

Comment: @1201 I like to think that problem can be solved by renaming the [gas] tag to [gnu-assembler], and then making [gas] a synonym of [gnu-assembler]. That way, anyone who tries to use [gas] will have the tag automatically changed to [gnu-assembler]. It isn't a guarantee, of course, but one *hopes* that if you are trying to ask a question about gasoline fuel, you'll notice the [gnu-assembler] tag, see that it's wrong, and go change/remove it.

Comment: Argee on the renaming - recently started to notice the `gas` tag on questions that are about google apps script issues (I frequent the tag). @CodyGray - although the renaming part seems to me a proper way to deal with the problem, I am unsure whether it will pay off to give askers a way to shoot themselves in the foot by linking (in my experience a quie a few of `google-apps-script` questions are asked by people who don't look twice at tags they add)

Comment: [Related discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216782/)

Comment: Related to the above "related discussion" link: @CodyGray Please don't make [tag:gas]  a synonym of [tag:gnu-assembler]. I think that it might be better to make it an synonym of [tag:google-apps-script] and could be used in instead of `gs` in tags like [tag:gs-installable-triggers] (`google-apps-script-installable-triggers` exceeds the 35 chars limit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Reference [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399725/1595451) to [What can be done to prevent [gas] tag ambiguity?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399396/1595451)

> [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) is now renamed to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler). [gnu-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-as) is a synonym of [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler).