# Improving Google Apps Script: tags, tag wikis, excerpts and refs

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

**Preface**

This project has [sprung up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398234/11407695) from the larger [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398230/what-to-do-with-how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development) as a standalone effort to make Google Apps Script tags, their excerpts, and wikis more fine-grained, detailed, and resource-full for them to become a viable alternative (alongside canonical Q&As) to long and hard to navigate community wiki reference lists or collections.

---

**Proposal**

I propose to coordinate the effort of updating tags and wikis for Google Apps Script-environment related Q&As here as a standalone project to improve visibility and provide a place for discussion of such changes to help reach consensus on trickier edits and involve the collective expertise of the community.

The proposal as it stands now is limited to the effort of the Google Apps Script community to test the water, but it would be great if we could expand the discussion to other areas that might need it as well.

We now have a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community)!

---

**Useful queries**

The queries below are meant to ease the process of monitoring tags and related questions (square brackets mean configurable [parameters]):

1. [Tags, their wikis, excerpts, and synonyms](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=google-apps-script&starts=1) that match [search term]
2. Tags [without tag wikis](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1252308) or excerpts
3. Tags with [pending wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1252310) suggested edits
4. [Well-received questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266713/positively-received-questions-with-tag-that-do-not-contain-text?tag=google-apps-script&text=documentation&includeText=yes&includeTag=yes) with [tag] and [text] (configurable)
5. [Percent of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1265553/percent-of-posts-tagged-with-only-tag-with-no-answers-and-low-views) tagged with [tag] and [low] views
6. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1284383) by users with reputation higher than [threshold]
7. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1256240/questions-with-tag-per-period-with-score-more-than-score?tag=google-apps-script&score=1&metric=day&offset=-7) with score over [threshold] (by period)
8. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1256455/how-many-questions-included-tag-that-was-later-removed) that was later removed + version [including initial state](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1263093/1555500/how-many-questions-tagged-with-tag-in-retag#resultSets) of the question
9. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1267286/posts-tagged-with-tag-that-contain-the-tag-as-title-prefix?tag=google-apps-script&offset=6) that have the [tag] as title prefix
10. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1262427#graph) that are tagged with Google API or product tag
11. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1262928/questions-by-tag-that-are-also-tagged-with-a-tag) that are also tagged with another [tag]
12. [Questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266704/links-to-questions-tagged-with-tag-no-comments-and-without-answers?tag=google-apps-script&answers=yes&offset=6&posted=yes&period=month), no comments and [without] answers
13. [Top users of the [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1275615/top-users-of-tag-with-positively-received-and-non-closed-posts?tag=google-apps-script) by positively received and non-closed posts
14. [Trend of questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261578/questions-posted-with-a-tag) and positive score
15. [Trend of the average score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1273515#graph) of upvoted answers on upvoted questions by year of creation
16. [Trend of questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1260020) that [do not] contain a [term]
17. [Trend of questions with [tag]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1310796/questions-with-tag-closed-as-duplicate?tag=google-apps-script#graph) that are closed as duplicate

---

**All tags GAS**

Google Apps Script main tags with `google-apps-script-*` prefix:

[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)
[google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api)

Related tags with `gs-*` prefix:

Cleared.

Closely related tags:

[urlfetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlfetch) (see Google App Engine [URL Fetch Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests))

APIs that have corresponding [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services):

[gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api)
[google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api)
[google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api)
[google-docs-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs-api)
[google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api)
[google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api)
[google-slides-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-slides-api)
[youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api)

---

**Pending tasks and recent updates**

> a lot of the tasks moved to the [community chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community) for greater velocity, so this question now includes long to middle term tasks.

The list contains pending changes and issues that need care. Please help if you can or participate in the discussion (done tasks can be found in [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398344/timeline)):

*Pending renaming / retagging / merging requests*

1. [Merge tag [google-hangouts] with [hangout]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402672/merge-tag-google-hangouts-with-hangout)

---

As of October, 6<sup>th</sup>, Google [announced the renaming](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/workspace/introducing-google-workspace) of G Suite to Google Workspace, therefore we now have a big project of updating affected tags on our hand. Currently pending requests are:

1. [Rename [google-apps-marketplace] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394343/rename-google-apps-marketplace-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Remove synonym [gsuite-addons] from [google-apps-script] and rename [gsuite-addons] to [google-workspace-add-ons]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402074/remove-synonym-gsuite-addons-from-google-apps-script-and-rename-gsuite-addo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

*Question tagging*

1. See query about questions that are tagged with a tag and have it duplicated in the title as prefix (cleanup needed)

*Tag wikis and excerpts*

Currently cleared

*Synonymizing (voting requests)*

Currently Cleared

If you have reservations or want to discuss, join the community chat room. Each synonym undergoes a preliminary discussion and internal voting process amongst experts and is decided by a majority vote.

---

**Related resources**

1. Help articles on: [excerpt editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)
2. Pending tag synonyms [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested)
3. Writing a [good tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318338/11407695)
4. Tutorials in tag wikis [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291237/11407695)
5. [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430/how-to-gather-support-for-tag-synonyms)

Comment: Why you think that it's confused with [tag:gae-quotas]? Why there should be two different tags (all Google Apps Script projects have a Google Cloud Project and Apps Script and App Engine are part of Google Cloud)

Comment: "google-services" could be misleading as Google offer other services than "[Google Apps Script] built-in Google Services"

Comment: Hi @Rubén - thank you for your comments! Regarding quotas - I would argue that [quotas for google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and [google-app-engine quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Resources) are two very distinct types of quotas . As for the confusion - I already retagged a couple of q. that were gae-tagged, but are about quotas for services. The second reason is that a search like [this one]([google-apps-script] [quota]) shows that there should be a more specific tag for service quotas than just "quota" tag. Also, during...

Comment: ...the past year, I started to notice that almost all questions that ask for assistance in understanding "service invoked too many times", etc or regarding available quotas commonly refer to service quotas specifically (not even mail sending limits). Regarding "google-services" - I don't like the wording very much as well, but that how they are called - "Quotas for Google Services" and all of them refer to built-in services. That said, I am not entirely sure these quotas refer only to built-in services, but AFAIK advanced services have their own, API-specific quotas.

Comment: Re:GAS editor wiki update "do not use" part - I think I agree that as it stands now "do not use for debugging help" is narrowing the scope (I used it in the same sense that help article [on on-topic questions uses it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) uses it, at least as far as I think I can grasp one) - since it is not approved yet I will change that. Sometimes it does indeed refer to debugging via script editor (although one might suggest adding a specific tag for Apps Script debugger built into the editor which we also lack, but that's likely not worth the fragmentation)...

Comment: ...And will also add (well, make more explicit, as the reference is there already) the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) reference to the wiki as well - missed it when updating and mention that the tag should be used for debug mode.

Comment: @Rubén - Re:editor wiki again - updated the suggestion to include the missed use case and reworded "do not" first point and tried to both keep the idea that the tag should not be used for help with code that just happens to run "in" the editor (have seen this pattern several times). See [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62383689/append-details-from-a-variable), for example (given what the question is about, I now consider adding a warning about not using it for document editors and permissions in general)

Comment: Now I'm thinking that the [tag:google-apps-script-editor] proposed tag wiki deserves it's own Q/A... (perhaps its own chat room)

Comment: IMHO [tag:google-documentation], [tag:google-services-quotas], [tag:advanced-google-services] look to be meta-tags and prone to be "abused" as the people who use [tag:google-apps-script] is a very small community compared to the community that uses a Google product/service/API. I think that we should use `google-apps-script-` *something* / `gs-` *something-that-exceeds-the-35-chars-limit*

Comment: @Rubén - yes, I considered this route, and my concern was that google-apps-script-quotas and gs-advanced-services can be confusing as people won't know these conventions we have (assuming the least amount of effort). Regarding google-documentation - this one I added to 1. Not create dissonance with already existing convention and 2. GAS will limit the meaning to documentation on GAS while the question may concern an advanced service docs or even REST API.
To sum up, I think that using the same names quotas and services are called in official documentation at least gives us a chance that...

Comment: ...users will be somewhat familiar with how they are called (and I think that those who don't read the documentation at all are beyond saving by definition - after all, [tag:appscript] keeps popping up instead of [tag:google-apps-script]. To elaborate some more on google-documentation - I was answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581313/are-google-apps-script-script-properties-actually-project-properties-what/62585458#62585458) that fell under the category of documentation issues

Comment: I propose leaving them as is (and I will be adding usage info for those that do not have one as soon as I get some extra time to spare - or maybe someone else will get to them first) and see what happens (I am happy to design a SEDE query for long-term management) - if there is any sign of abuse, I will be the first to create a tag under the guidelines you mentioned and request synonimization of the current tag. As for any GAS tags we are missing (not sure if we do, though) - I totally support your way of thinking and these were my guidelines as well.

Comment: I disagree with the currently proposed excerpt and wiki of [tag:advanced-google-services] as they are wrote as if they were part of a site about [tag:google-apps-script]. IMHO in the context of [so], they make the tag look as a meta tag.

Comment: @Rubén - could you please clarify what you mean by "part of a site"? Re:wiki excerpt - I would argue that the disambiguation with built-in services and REST APIs is the "when" of the excerpt. Probably lacks in "why", I agree - happy to rewrite if we can find a common ground - maybe [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216162/google-apps-script-tag-wikis-and-excerpts)? I also oriented on the success of: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26437181) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26433306), but maybe I missed the mark here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400126) post and a lot of discussion within the community, It was decided that most branches of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) needed to go. But there doesn't seem to be any combined record of these matters in the meta. Therefore, I've decided to add this answer mainly to record the actions done by the community hitherto.

The discussion was mainly held in the [official community chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community) for the last three months. Though the initial decisions were disputed by [one user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n), the user left further discussions in the chat room of their own accord and All decisions were unanimous thereafter. The initial decisions were unanimous, save one user mentioned above.

The following tags were deemed unnecessary by the community and synonymized to the parent tag: [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Some of these tags have separate meta posts/voting chat rooms associated with it. They are linked below, if available.

1. [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) - [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400215/synonymize-sub-tag-google-apps-script-web-application-to-main-tag-google-apps), [Vote room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219659/vote-google-apps-script-web-applicationgoogle-apps-script)
2. [gas-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas-web-app) - See 1 above
3. [google-apps-script-html-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-html-service) - See 1 above
4. [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers) - [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399489/should-google-apps-script-simple-triggers-and-gs-instal),  [Vote room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218706/vote-google-apps-script-simple-trigger-gs-installable-triggers-vs-triggers)
5. [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers) - See 4 above
6. [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) - [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400145/merge-google-apps-script-editor-to-google-apps-script)
7. [google-apps-script-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-project) - [Related Meta Answer and comments chain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400146/)
8. [google-apps-script-dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-dashboard) - Related to 7
9. [google-apps-script-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-menu) - Related to 7
10. [google-apps-script-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-libraries) - Related to 7
11. [google-apps-script-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-runtime) - Related to 7
12. [google-apps-script-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-addon)
13. [google-sheets-custom-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-custom-function)
14. [google-sheets-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-macros)
15. [gsuite-addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite-addons)
16. [gmail-addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-addons)
17. [advanced-google-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-google-services)

All synonyms proposals were discussed in official chat room before synonymizing(even without meta posts or vote rooms). Anyone can search the  relevant tag they're interested in - in the [official chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community)  for the recorded discussion.

Answer (score 4):

The main language [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) has way too many branches. I believe most of them are unnecessary and should be debranched/merged into the main tag itself. The following factors should be considered when creating new branches or consolidating old branches:

- **Concept division:** Is the [google-apps-script-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-branch) proposed, a sufficiently different concept to warrant a separate tag? This should be voted upon by **subject experts/badge holders** of the tag.
- **Alternatives:** Could a [google-apps-script-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-branch) be sufficiently  described by  a other tag or a couple of LEGO tags? LEGO tags, in general,  have pretty good organic growth  built in and should be preferred where possible.  Eg: Prefer [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)+[arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) over [google-apps-script-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-arrays).
- **Quantity:** Percent of questions that are or will be tagged with the [google-apps-script-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-branch). And whether it  is significant enough to warrant the tag division.
- **Organic growth**:

  - Whether [google-apps-script-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-branch) is added naturally(organically) by question askers  or Was it added inorganically by tag editors?
  - Organic growth is preferable to inorganic growth. This depends on the

    - Tag name: Whether  the name is naturally recognizable as a specific concept to new users or the typical audience of the tag without the need for usage guidelines/wikis.
    - Tag length: Growth is inversely proportional to Tag length.
    - Tag concept popularity: How popular is the concept proposed popular among the intended audience?
  - If the tag's growth is mainly inorganic, it'll create unnecessary burdens on the tag editors, annoy other users(because questions are frequently edited(mostly in bulk) to just add the tags as deemed necessary by one editor),actively harm by hiding questions from potential answerers.
  - If added inorganically, how many users are adding the tag? If the tag editing burden is carried by a lot of users with no one user's contribution significantly higher, then the growth may continue despite it's inorganic nature.

I propose that for a tag to be branched, At least 3 of the  above 4 criteria be satisfied.

Comment: I like that approach - answering these questions can be formalized and verified with data, not abstract discussions on usefulness.

Comment: @oguzismail I invited almost all gold badge holders to discussion. Only one showed up. That too he hasn't made a meta post/ answer even when pushed. Highly unlikely  that we have unity. And that is just 1 criteria. They  have to decide whether the concept is sufficiently different to warrant a branch.

Comment: @oguzismail *how are -dashboard, -quota and google-documentation on-topic on SO?* I don't think they are. But here we are.

Comment: @oguzismail - two of which currently actively participate in discussions ( btw, TheMaster, congratulations on the badge ). Proportional voting system based on a level of tag badge is a very good way to determine SME.

Comment: @oguzismail - re: documentation, actually it has one question now, the one I decided to create it long ago for, and it is on-topic in my opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581313/are-google-apps-script-script-properties-actually-project-properties-what/62585458#62585458. That said, if it is decided to deal away with it, I won't be against it

Comment: @oguzismail That'd be great. But even Oleg doesn't agree with me on that I think. We currently have a plan to go full meta for each tag here. :sigh:

Comment: @TheMaster - yes, unfortunately, there is a couple of tags I disagree... But that is what the discussion is for, after all, and due process - so we do not iterate over and over again. Even if I won't like a decision on some of them, I will be content and happy if we did our best to discuss and voted upon what to do next.

Comment: @oguzismail Exactly. It's pointless. Ruben started all this I think. By full meta, I mean full discussion on for/ against to show consensus.

Comment: @oguzismail - at least we will have a point of reference and potentially a consensus. So far we have several highly active users in the related tags that agreed on follow the rules if they are discussed and voted upon. I am a bit scared to hear about the idea of leaving anyone out of the decision process on a community-driven website.

Comment: @OlegValter I agree. It should be all inclusive and all voices who wants to speak should be heard. My contention is simply that this painful process was not undertaken when someone unilaterally created the tag and retagged.

Comment: @TheMaster I understand your sentiment too and fully agree. I guess there was none when this happened? I think we made big progress in making creation and edits (at least in one domain) a less vigilante-style one and more formalized one.

Comment: @oguzismail *That kind of contradicts with This should be voted upon by subject experts/badge holders of the tag* No. It doesn't. Subject experts decide whether a concept is sufficiently different.  And I agree that badge holders should have more power. I disagree with silencing dissenting opinions. All voices should be heard. But decision should belong to stake holders, who actually visit the tag and answer. Public voices also mean moderators can override any decision made by badge holders.

Comment: @oguzismail - why does it? I don't think my vote should count the same as the vote of [tag:sql] gold badge holder (or even bronze for that matter) and expect the same from others in the matters of apps script. Who else can we consider SME's as not gold > silver > bronze holders?

Comment: Google Apps Script is not a language.  The language is JavaScript, and if the developer uses CLASP they could use TypeScript.

Comment: Is there a FAQ (or a related canonical Q/A) about "LEGO tags"?

Comment: Is there a FAQ (or a related canonical Q/a) about "organical tag growth"?

Comment: @Rubén well, yeah, technically it is more correct to be referred to as a scripting platform. I think TheMaster meant "tag", judging from the post? Re:q/a - good question, no I do not know of one, but I will look for (I only know of similar discussions on tags like [tag:git], that might be helpful). Re:TS - afaik it has to be compiled to JS to be used with GAS, isn't it?

Comment: @OlegValter According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/ TypeScript is a language. I don't know how CLASP compiles it to JS (in this context that is irrelevant, I think).

Comment: @Rubén - I did not mean to say TS is not a language, sorry if came off as such, I meant it can't be [used directly in GAS projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript). Probably just uses the `tsc` command.

Comment: @OlegValter I mentioned an "if" regarding TS :)

Comment: @Rubén - ah, I finally got what you meant by "if" :) Come to think of it, there is a couple of extra definitions of GAS: "rapid application development platform". On the other hand, the fact TS is *compiled to GAS*. I suppose we should terminologically treat it the same way as Node.js

Comment: The "organic approach" is certainly more intuitive and will lead to less wrong tagging by new users. An inexperienced user will most likely only tag his question with `google-apps-script` and might be overwhelmed when he sees 15 different tags including the word `google-apps-script`, while a more experienced user can refine the branching of his question by adding additional tags - like the above mentioned `google-apps-script`+`arrays`.

Answer (score 2):

## Tag naming convention

Proposed tag naming convention for tags that are about Google Apps Script stuff

### google-apps-script-

Whenever it's possible use `google-apps-script-` for tags that are about Google Apps Script stuff (child tags)

Why? Because searching `[google-apps-script*]` will show something like this:

[image]

### gs-

When it's not possible to use `google-apps-script`, i.e. the tag will not be allowed because its length exceeds the 35 character limit, use `gs-`

Why? Because searching `[gs-*]` will show something like this:

[image]

> `gs-` might not be very fortunate as it's currently used for Google Sheet conditional formatting, Google Sheets vlookup function and for GS Collections that is a Java framework. It was suggested to use `gas-` but its [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) is already used and being discussed in [Rename [gas] to [gnu-assembler]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397525/1595451)

Related

- [Rename [gas] to [gnu-assembler]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397525/1595451)

Comment: I just proposed [tag:gs] as a synonym of [tag:google-apps-script] --> Please vote https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/synonyms

Comment: In context,`gs` means `google-sheets` and not apps script. For eg, gs-conditional-formatting means **google-sheets**-conditional-formatting

Comment: @TheMaster As Google Sheets and and Google Apps Script are very closely related  I don't see a problem, anyway, could you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: By the way from the tag excerpt of [tag:gs-collections] -> "GS Collections is a collections framework for Java."

Comment: They're closely related, but not interchangeable. For eg, `gs-vlookup` has no meaning or place in the context of apps script. `gas` would've been perfect if it was not already taken.

Comment: [tag:gas] is already taken. From it's tag excerpt -> Relevant topics include Gnu Assembler (GAS) macros, machine dependent syntax, linkage and file format issues. Do use for generic assembler questions; the CPU tags are meant for this.

Comment: By the way when [tag:gs-vlookup] was created the tag name length limit was very short, maybe the same happened with [tag:gs-conditional-formatting]. I'm wondering if we should ask that them be renamed to `google-sheets-`*something* so they will be included when searching for `[google-sheets*]`

Comment: That sounds like a nice idea. Still, ``gas`` would be perfect. Can't we rename gnu ``gas`` to ``gnu-a`` or somethings like that? It's got less than 1k questions.

Comment: Well, I think that we should work a bit on the arguments for that and make a new Q and then ask the help of a diamond moderator.

Comment: Furthermore, gnu`gas` has no subdivisions or related tags starting with `gas-`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216782/discussion-between-ruben-and-themaster).

Comment: To be honest, if all apps script tags (`google-apps-script-*`)are renamed(`gas-*`), it'll be much easier for everyone.

Comment: **No, we can't just start calling the Gnu Assembler "`gnu-a` or something like that", since *that's not what it is called*.** The official name is "gas", so that's what folks are going to call it. Questions about the Gnu Assembler are at least equally on-topic for Stack Overflow, if not more so, than questions about Google Apps, so Google Apps can't just take over `gas`. If *anything*, we'd ban `gas` outright to avoid ambiguity. But I'd rather not.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think `gas` is the official name. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler) says it's  "The GNU Assembler, **commonly** known as gas or simply as" . The [official page](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) also doesn't explicitly state "gas". It states "as- Gnu-Assembler" and There is a single mention of "gas" , when referring to news files. I'd like to make the case that "gas" is much more known as "google-apps-script" than "gnu-assembler"- "much more" as in more questions tagged to refer to apps script by initial posters. I

Comment: Yes, the tool is commonly known as `gas`. That's what everyone calls it, including me, who works with it every day. Assuming that something is minor or unpopular just because you've never heard of it doesn't scale to a site the size of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray Although it's true that I've never heard of it or used it before  running into tag name similarity, The assumption that it is minor/unpopular is based on  number of questions in the tag (754 vs 32855-> Apps script at least 43x more popular). In addition, none of the `gas`-assembler related tags  use the keyword `gas`, while apps script has so many divisions starting with `google-apps-script-*`. Prima facie, These are my reasons to even attempt to  request the switch from `gas`: ``assembler`` to `google-apps-script`-> for the sake of all of SO community.

Comment: @CodyGray `Yes, the tool is commonly known as gas. That's what everyone calls it, including me, who works with it every day.` The same can be said for the scripting language too, and I feel this argument is dangerously bordering on argumentum ad ignorantiam. I see no reason that changing `gas` to `gnu-assembler` would cause any confusion, it is objectively clearer as a tag and as TheMaster has pointed out, the numbers support the use of `google-apps-script` related questions far exceeds the frequency in which GNU assembler related questions are asked.

Comment: It's *argumentum ad ignorantiam* on both sides. All these claims are doing is proving that more people use Google Apps than use gas. It doesn't prove the accuracy of the names.

Comment: Additionally, while  an argument can be made for `gs` to become a synonym for `google-apps-script` (*`gs-*` tags can be renamed to `google-sheet-*` as even `google-sheet-conditional-formatting` will stay inside the 35 character limit) this will not alleviate the confusion brought about by the `gas` tag. In addition to the problems I raised with [`appscript`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390701/) last October, I have unfortunately lost count how many times I have removed `gas` from erroneously-tagged `google-apps-script` questions.

Comment: A week later (forgot to follow the answer): @CodyGray - can [tag:gas] be renamed to [tag:gnu-assembler] as proposed before (you [said that is a possibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397525/rename-gas-to-gnu-assembler#comment771148_397525) earlier) and, judgment of solomon-style, **`gas` not to be made a synonym of either** - it can be done that way, right? Those who are new can't create tags, and a person established enough to do so will likely check what happened to `gas` and find out that it is named `gnu-assembler`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the suggest edit for the tag wiki of [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor)

I disagree with

> **Do not use for questions:**
>
> 1. seeking debugging help, use appropriate language tag instead

because sometimes the debugging is done by using the Apps Script editor and some of those questions are derived from how the Editor debugging features works.

---

Nowadays it's possible to use different IDES to work with Google Apps Script thanks to [google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) / [clasp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clasp)

I think that [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) should be used for questions that are about using the Google Apps Script editor, including but not limited to:

1. Creating, editing and deleting *.gs and *.html files
2. Editing the manifest (`appscript.json`)

   - Custom oAuth scopes
3. Disabling/enabling the new runtime (Chrome V8)
4. Running code from the editor
5. Debugging code from the editor, including

   - Using Logger
   - Using the Execution Transcript
6. Enabling/disabling advanced services
7. Adding and managing libraries
8. Managing deployments (publishing a new version, etc) of

   - Editor add-ons
   - G Suite / Gmail add-ons
   - Web Applications
9. ...

Questions that should not include [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) are questions about, but not limited to:

1. managing (creating, editing, running, deleting, debugging) Google Apps Script projects using CLASP, instead use [clasp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clasp)
2. using Google Apps Script Dashboard (https://script.google.com), instead use [google-apps-script-dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-dashboard)
3. using Stackdriver, instead use [stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackdriver)
4. ...

---

Questions that are a good fit for this tag

- [Why does google script editor stop paren matching after 100 lines in a function and does it affect the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13711260/1595451)

Questions that currently has this tag but it should be removed

- [External Editor Support for Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24739294/1595451)
- [Google app script desktop ide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48983003/1595451)

  The question ask for alternatives for the Google Apps Script editor. Nowadays it could include [clasp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clasp) and [google-apps-script-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api)

---

This tag could be used together with

- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) as this is a broader (and older) tag
- [v8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/v8) when the question is about the new Google Apps Script runtime
- [rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rhino) when the question is about the old Google Apps Script runtime
- [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) for questions about applying a debugging technique in the Google Apps Script editor
- [google-apps-script-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-libraries) for questions about using the Google Apps Escript editor for managing Google Apps Script libraries but not for using JavaScript libraries like [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

Comment: Rubén, as I mentioned in the comment to the question, I agree with you on that one and already made edits to the proposal, please do check the [new revision](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26433933) - should be now better-worded + has a direct reference to debugger guide

Comment: Re: [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216162/google-apps-script-editor-tag-wiki)

Comment: Btw, Rubén, is the edit for the editor tag still pending (unfortunately I can't see reviews yet, only the status?)

Comment: @OlegValter The tag wiki is still waiting to be approved.

Comment: I see - maybe worth adding to the list in the question to help visibility?

Comment: I'm not sure how effective that will be but I think that more effective to make a new post but that it's not a priority for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Apps Script libraries**

> [google-apps-script-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-libraries) is now a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

A subproject of this effort regards the improvement of references to well-known dependencies. It would be a good idea to form a list of libraries to help users with one of the more difficult tasks in Google Apps Script - managing project dependencies (due to lack of module system).

A good example of a well-known library is Eric's [OAuth 2.0 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2), which is officially recommended. All libraries mentioned **must** be deployed as an Apps Script Library, **should** follow [guidelines and best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#creating_a_library) of the official guide where applicable. The library also **should** have significant usage and you should be prepared to show that this is the case.

For easy reference: [library database thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/google-apps-script-community/sXO6_vCIbgI) on Google Apps Script Community.

---

Embedded preview of GAS libraries [open database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lk6OClOPA8p94fspQrs8-M-W080tb244U-fWGqvnApk):

```js
const createIframe = ({ parent = document.body, src } = {}) => {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.width = "100%";
  iframe.height = "300px";
  iframe.src = src;
  
  parent.append(iframe);
  
  return iframe;
};


(() => {

  createIframe({
    src : "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS4gVVYZ0L566MiS0_uXu3pQeeRzF__aIQO8l9iuIjq_j8DmyibSwjEo1hkJCyTkkiFcYCWrQnjfsPW/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"
  });

})();
```

---