# Merge tag [google-hangouts] with [hangout]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

**Proposal**

It is proposed to merge the [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) into [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) and transfer the wiki info to the latter without<sup>0</sup> making [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) a synonym.

**Reasoning**

1. It is explicitly stated in the [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) excerpt not to use it in favor of [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout).
2. [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) tag breaks the tradition (see SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=google-&starts=1)) of prefixing Google product and APIs tags with `google-*`. Also the official name of the product is [Google Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com/).
3. [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) should not be made a synonym of [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) because the "hangout" name is not specific to Google Hangouts and can be used by other products, libraries, and APIs.

**Tag Info**

- [hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) has both [excerpt and wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hangout/info) that can be transferred (needs an update, though as Google+ is deprecated, also there is no usage guidance).
- [google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) does not have a [tag wiki or excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-hangouts/info) and only has notice of not using it.

**Tag stats**

[google-hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) is still sporadically used despite the warning (3-year graph of positively received questions):

[image: google hangouts trend]

[hangout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangout) is frequently used as expected from the main tag:

[image: hangout trend]

---

<sup>0</sup> That said, if it is deemed beneficial to make the tag a synonym, there are no objections.

Comment: It would be good if you include in your analysis [tag:hangouts-chat] (by the way, nowadays the official name is Google Chat, the former name was Google Hangouts Chat) i.e. Are questions having [tag:hangouts] / [tag:google-hangouts] that should be retagged as [tag:hangouts-chat]?

Comment: @Rubén not sure I follow - could you please clarify if you want to expand the merge request to include the Google Chat or just include the information about it in the request / tag wiki since they are related products?

Comment: Another related tag [tag:hangouts-api]. In this case the related API is deprecated.

Comment: "hangouts" is not specific to a single product, even Google used it for two different products: Google Hangouts and Google Hangouts Chat, the later now is named Google Chat by the way we also have [tag:google-chat]... I'm not sure if this is in favor or against the merge without first doing a tag cleanup. Anyway, in this merge request you might mention that this should be considered by those that will be working on the usage guidelines of the "new" [tag:google-hangouts]

Comment: @Rubén - I see, thank you. I think both can be done in parallel - I don't see anything blocking us from merging the [tag:hangout] and [tag:google-hangouts] (and you provided the info for other readers already), but [tag:google-chat] also needs some love - I am going to make a separate request after some digging in.